# consultar 2 tablas para ver que registros no estan en la primera tabla

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo 2 tablas de personas de 1 sistema el cual cuenta con 2 versiones, cada versión con base de datos diferente, lo que quiero saber es que personas de la `tabla t_evaluacion_vulnerabilidad` no estan en la tabla `t_evaluacion_dean`, aca les comparto el codigo para consultar

```
select cedula from personas1.t_persona_vulnerabilidad where cedula not in (select cedula from personas1.t_persona_dean)
```

Al correrlo de esta forma no me trae ningún resultado.

Comment: Revisa la pregunta ya que no tiene nada que ver con el código, mencionas las tablas `t_evaluacion_vulnerabilidad` y `t_evaluacion_dean`, sin embargo el código menciona `t_persona_vulnerabilidad` y `t_persona_dean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opino que seria conveniente utilizar NOT EXISTS, Si deseas conseguir los registros que no están en otra tabla;

```
SELECT cedula 
  FROM personas1.t_persona_vulnerabilidad t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM personas1.t_persona_dean t2
                    WHERE t2.cedula= t1.cedula)
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos me parece que tu que tienes tu consulta bien, ahora bien en tu preguntas dices que las tablas estan en base de datos diferentes y no veo que haces referencias a las base de datos por ejempo asi. Mira ver si esto te funciona.

```
select cedula from db1.personas1.t_persona_vulnerabilidad where cedula not in (select cedula from db2.personas1.t_persona_dean)
```

Comment: si es que para poder trabajar mas mejor cree un schema y alli restaure las 2 tablas

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Encuentro **inconsistencia entre tu problema planteado y tu ejemplo**. Nombrás a la tabla "*t_evaluacion_vulnerabilidad*" y "*t_evaluacion_dean*" en tu planteo y luego haces referencia a las tablas "*personas1.t_persona_vulnerabilidad*" y "*personas1.t_persona_dean*".

**Planteo**:
Veo que tu consulta SQL se encuentra bien redactada y al parecer... es coherente. Por ende, significa que todas las personas almacenadas en tu tabla *t_evaluacion_dean*, se encuentran  a su vez almacenadas en *t_evaluacion_vulnerabilidad*.

**Conclusión**:
NO hay ninguna persona en la Tabla nº 1 (t_evaluacion_dean) que NO esté en la Tabla nº 2 (t_evaluacion_vulnerabilidad).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta forma

```
 SELECT *
  FROM personas1.t_persona_vulnerabilidad t1
 WHERE t1.cedula NOT IN (SELECT cedula
                     FROM personas1.t_persona_dean)
```

Answer (score -1):

HICE UNA PRUEBA EN UNA DATA REAL Y ME FUNCIONO USANDO EL NOT EXISTS, ejemplo

```
select * from sdm_inmuebles i 
where c16_estado='ACEPTADO'
 and not exists (select null from sdd_inmueble_abonos s
 where s.i8_inmueble_id=i.i8_inmueble_id and c8_tributo_id='TSINMALU' and i8_periodo=’201901’)
```

aca le digo que me muestre todos los registros que estan en la tabla de inmuebles y que no hayan cancelado su servicio de alumbrado publico en el periodo 201901